# Error in Isodepth: Points are not in general position

Tags: r

I want to run the `isodepth` on two dimensional data `x` such as following:

```
xDepth <- isodepth(x)
```

But getting the following error:

> Error in isodepth(x) : Points are not in general position.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have considered the [documentation of `depth` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/depth/depth.pdf) you can find an input variable which is called `mustdith` and described like:

> Should dithering be applied? Used when data set is not in general
>   position or a numerical problem is encountered.

Hence, it would be enough to `TRUE` this input:

```
xData <- isodepth(x, mustdith = TRUE)
```